# How do I copy my private PDBs into my symbol cache, using the symbol tree folder structure?

Tags: windows, symbols, windbg, pdb-files

I have a set of PDBs and I want to store them in my cache so that they'll be available to various tools (windbg.exe, wpa.exe) and so that I know they'll be backed up *somewhere*, rather than risk overwriting a PDB that corresponds to an important ETL trace that I took the previous day. It's easy to use symchk.exe to pull a PDB into your cache, but I want to push my own PDB into it.

There's gotta be a quick easy command with some debugging tool that does this.

Comment: Does setting symbol path as `srv*c:\symbols_cache*f:\my_symbol_source` help? note, they are separated by `*` & not `;`.

Comment: @anishsane My goal here is to put my own PDBs into a symsrv-style folder (C:\symbols\myBinary.pdb\[hash]\myBinary.pdb) so that I can work smoothly in the future without having to adjust my symbol path all the time, and without having to remember which symbol path to use with which ETL trace. Also, if I were trying to do what your comment suggests, I'd use syntax `srv*c:\symbols_cache;f:\my_symbol_source` (with a semicolon) so that it does not signify that "my_symbol_source" is symsrv-style (and instead contains the PDBs in a flat folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up using: (by example)

```
C:\Debuggers\symstore.exe add /f C:\Users\marcusl\Desktop\ieframe.pdb /s C:\symbols /t ""
```